# How to show that given a catagory $\scr C$ and two terminal objects $X$ and $Y$ in $\scr C$, they are isomorphic.

Tags: category-theory

I know that there are unique morphisms (functions in the categories of sets) $\delta_X: X \to Y$ and $\delta_Y: Y \to X$, but I am unable to show, either diagrammatically, or otherwise, that $\delta_Y \circ \delta_X=1_X$ and $\delta_X \circ \delta_Y=1_Y$.

Comment: Hint: there is also a unique morphism $X \to X$! (btw, it's bad practice to use "function" to refer to morphisms in an arbitrary category)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I would appreciate if you could expand on it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Aren't they $\delta_Y \circ \delta_X$ and $1_X$ *two* morphisms from $X$ to $X$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $X$ is a terminal object, there is a unique morphism $A\to X$ for any object $A$ in the category. In particular, there must be a unique morphism $X\to X$. Now $\delta_Y\circ\delta_X$ is one such morphism. On the other hand, every object has the identity morphism, so $1_X:X\to X$ is another such morphism. By uniqueness, they must equal. Similarly, we have $\delta_X\circ \delta_Y=1_Y$.